# XAML Image Resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I add some pictures as ressource to my project (for example I put them into the folder "ressources").
Now I'm using them with:

```
<Image Name="_ImageName" Width="100" Height="100" Source="Resources\HalloPicA.png"/>
<Image Name="_ImageName" Width="100" Height="100" Source="Resources\HalloPicB.png"/>
```

... and so one.

Imagine now I will change the folder "Resources" to "MyResources". The Problem I have to change it everywhere in the XAML-code.
Is there a better way existing? In c#-Code I would declare a member variable from typ string like:

```
privat _FolderName = "Resources";
```

and use this member variable in this way:

```
Image newImage = Image.FromFile(_FolderName +"HalloPicA.png");
```

Hopefully my problems are clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Property Binding and Value Converters to do this.
For example:

```
    <Image Name="_ImageName" Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding Path=imgA, Converter={StaticResource imgPathConverter}}" />
```

Where your imgPathConverter is the class that can convert image name in your "qualified" image path.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create separate resource dictionary, or put it in `Application.Resources`, with `BitmapImage` resources:

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="/MyAssemblyName;component/MyPath/myImage.png" x:Key="imageKey"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and then when you want to use it

```
<Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{StaticResource imageKey}"/>
```

this way when folder changes you'll need to change it only in one file